# Convert PySpark Dense Column Vectors into Rows

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, melt

I have a data-frame with 3 columns and every entry is a dense vector of same length.
How can I melt the Vector entries?

Current data-frame:

column1  |   column2   |

[1.0,2.0,3.0]|[10.0,4.0,3.0]

[5.0,4.0,3.0]|[11.0,26.0,3.0]

[9.0,8.0,7.0]|[13.0,7.0,3.0]

Expected:

column1|column2

1.0 . 10.0

2.0 . 4.0

3.0 . 3.0

5.0 . 11.0

4.0 . 26.0

3.0 . 3.0

9.0 . 13.0

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Let's create the initial DataFrame:

```
myValues = [([1.0,2.0,3.0],[10.0,4.0,3.0]),([5.0,4.0,3.0],[11.0,26.0,3.0]),([9.0,8.0,7.0],[13.0,7.0,3.0])]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['column1','column2'])
df.show()
+---------------+-----------------+
|        column1|          column2|
+---------------+-----------------+
|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]| [10.0, 4.0, 3.0]|
|[5.0, 4.0, 3.0]|[11.0, 26.0, 3.0]|
|[9.0, 8.0, 7.0]| [13.0, 7.0, 3.0]|
+---------------+-----------------+
```

**Step 2:** Now, `explode` both the columns, but after we `zip` the arrays. Here we know before hand that the length of `list/array` is 3.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, struct
tmp = explode(array(*[
    struct(col("column1").getItem(i).alias("column1"), col("column2").getItem(i).alias("column2"))
    for i in range(3)
]))
df=(df.withColumn("tmp", tmp).select(col("tmp").getItem("column1").alias('column1'), col("tmp").getItem("column2").alias('column2')))
df.show()
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|    1.0|   10.0|
|    2.0|    4.0|
|    3.0|    3.0|
|    5.0|   11.0|
|    4.0|   26.0|
|    3.0|    3.0|
|    9.0|   13.0|
|    8.0|    7.0|
|    7.0|    3.0|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.

Comment: No worries. Can you accept it as answer?